# htaccess MIME type css read as text/html

Tags: html, .htaccess

Before you reference similar questions: I did actually do research yet no post solved my issue.

I literally have the most basic code you can imagine yet one of the most basic things won't work. The CSS file is interpreted as text/html while I need it to be a read as a stylesheet. This is due to my .htaccess file even though I explicitly added the AddType thing.

Here's my HTML:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>EASY-Online</title>
        <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            test
        </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
AddType text/css .css
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,T=text/css]
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css"> try this..!

Comment: @HemaNandagopal How would this solve my issue? The markup is fine. It's to do with the .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found this to fix my issue:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
```

I added this directly above the RewriteRule. Apparently this allows the described
extentions to be reachable by navigating to them instead of redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

->(<- ERROR in line 1,2 and 3 in character 13

try this: 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l